# Add alpha to view VS Add alpha to UIColor

Tags: ios, swift, alpha, uicolor

Is writing this :

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.9)
```

Equivalent to this:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
view.alpha = 0.9
```

if not, what is the difference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple explanation

**Case 1:**

```
viewMain.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.9)
```

it will reduce the alpha color of the particular view i.e. `viewMain` here.

**Case 2:**

```
viewMain.alpha = 0.5
```

It will reduce the opacity of the view and if viewMain have multiple views then all views alpha will be reduced that amount.

**Example :**

Let be your view hierarchy is like this

```
viewMain
     -> view1
         -> view2
```

Now from **Case1**, alpha of `ViewMain` will be reduced only. But in **Case 2** alpha of `viewMain, view1, view2` will be reduced.

If you have no hierarchy, then both are same.

[image]

If you have view hierarchy, then it makes effect like below

[image]

Comment: let's forget about the subviews, does it give the same look for the `viewMain` (same color) ?

Comment: @iOSGeek Check the output result in the answer. If still Have doubt then ask.

Answer (score 2):

No both are not Equivalent

**Case 1.** Will give opacity(transparency) to UIColor only

**Case 2.** Will give opacity(transparency) to whole UIView

Using second all text and other object(Subviews) will also transparency applied.

You can understand more with below image

```
colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5) //First view Code

viewMain.alpha = 0.5 // second view code
```

both view has blue background colour and black colour text

[image]

So when which one should use :-

**Case 1.** Use when you want only transparency of UIColor Or You want to show views behind the main view with main object as clear as they actually are.

**Case 2.** Use when you want to show whole view with transparency.

Comment: but does that give the same result (color) for the view ?

Comment: @iOSGeek No as you can see transparency in UIColor is different from other

Answer (score 1):

The content in the UIView is affected by changing the alpha of the UIView itself. Changing it for example to 0.5 will change (well, look like) the subviews in the UIView to alpha 0.5 as well.

Changing the background color will not have the behaviour: the subviews are not affected.

Comment: let's forget about the subviews, does it give the same look for the `view` (same color) ?